# Which Lua function is better to use?

Tags: performance, math, lua

I took two ways to round numbers to decimals. First function just rounds the number:

```
function round(num)
    local under = math.floor(num)
    local over = math.floor(num) + 1
    local underV = -(under - num)
    local overV = over - num
    if overV > underV then
        return under
    else
        return over
    end
end
```

The next two functions use this function to round a number to decimals:

```
function roundf(num, dec)
    return round(num * (1 * dec)) / (1 * dec)
end

function roundf_alt(num, dec)
    local r = math.exp(1 * math.log(dec));
    return round(r * num) / r;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply

```
function round(num)
  return num >= 0 and math.floor(num+0.5) or math.ceil(num-0.5)
end
```

Instead of `math.floor(num) + 1` you can simply use `math.ceil(num)` btw.

Why do you multiply with 1 multiple times?

There are many things to consider when rounding numbers. Please do some research on how to handle special cases.

Comment: The question is not what function is simlier, but is using variables and then using them in function makes code run faster or not?

Comment: @EadwineYoun this sentence doesn't make sense. having excess multiplications in your code doesn't necessarily make things faster. having 2 calls to math.floor instead of one is also not very performant. multiplications usually take less time than function calls. I pointed out a few flaws in your code that cost time. if you're interested in performance differences just measure the time....